# Выполнение асинхронной функции через ajax и php

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Никак не могу подружится с jQuery :)

Здравствуйте, есть проблемы с `change`. Есть форма с селектором город и район. Задача: когда пользователь в селекторе выбирает город, должна выполнится следующая асинхронная функция через `ajax` и `php` ("Вытащить все районы, где районГорода = 'город'"), вот `ajax`  запрос:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#city").change(function(){var myChoice = $('#city :selected').val();

    var data = {myChoice: myChoice}
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST", url: "../blocks/change.php", data: data, dataType: 'json', success: function(data){

        var top_list = data.myrowRaion; // содержимое новых элементов
        var items = "<option>"; // вставляемый html-текст
        $mylist = $('#raion'); // необходимый список

        for (var i=0; i< top_list.length; i++)
          items +=  top_list[i] + '</option>';
        $mylist.append(items);

    }});

  });
});
```

а вот PHP код:

```
<?php

include("../blocks/bd.php");

if (isset($_POST['myChoice'])) {
    $myChoice = $_POST['myChoice'];
}

if (isset($myChoice)) {
    $resultRaion = mysql_query("SELECT raion, id FROM raion WHERE idCity = '$myChoice' ", $db);
    if (!$resultRaion) {
        echo "<p>Отправьте код на почту san-goldencity@mail.ru:</p>";
        exit(mysql_error());
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($resultRaion) > 0) {
        $myrowRaion = mysql_fetch_array($resultRaion);

    } else {
        echo "<p>Таблицы еще пустые, записей отствует</p>";

        exit();
    }
}

$myrowRaion[] = $myrowRaion;
echo json_encode($myrowRaion);

?>
```

вот форма кода:

<select name="city" id="city">
         <?
                  $resultCity = mysql_query("SELECT city, id FROM city ",$db);
                if (!$resultCity)
                {echo "<p>Отправьте код ошибки по данному почту san-goldencity@mail.ru:</p>";
                exit (mysql_error());}

```
            if (mysql_num_rows($resultCity) > 0)
            {
                $myrowCity = mysql_fetch_array($resultCity);

                do

                {
                printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",$myrowCity["id"], $myrowCity["city"]); 
                }
                while ($myrowCity = mysql_fetch_array($resultCity));

            }
            else 
            {
            echo "<p>Таблицы еще пустые, записей отствует</p>";

            exit ();
            }
            ?>
    </select>
<p class="formP">Район:</p>
    <select name="raion" id="raion">
    <option>Кутузовка</option>
    <option>Заречка</option>
    <option>15мкрн</option>
    <option>новый город</option>
    </select>
```

Помогите, что я не так делаю, подскажите?

Comment: Ну кто нибудь ответьте пожалуйста)

Comment: ошибку какую-нить выдает ?

Comment: нет вообще без действии(

Comment: в bd.php $_POST['myChoice'] приходит ?

что находится в $myrowRaion после выполнения запроса ?

Comment: а firebug  ?

Comment: firebug пишет TypeError: $("#city") is null

Comment: код страницы с формой можно увидеть ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Где у Вас происходит подключение `jquery`?

UPD:

1. Посмотрел ваш index.php и увидел что вы используете и jquery и mootools. Ошибка у вас из-за того что jquery конфликтует с объектом $ библиотеки mootools.
2. Решение: использовать [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)
3. Один из вариантов(по ссылке их несколько) исправления ошибки    TypeError: $("#city") is null:

   ```
   jQuery.noConflict();
   (function($) {  
     $(function() {  
         $("#city").change(function(){var myChoice = $("#city :selected").val();
   ```

   .......................................................................................................

   ```
     });  
   });  
   })(jQuery);
   ```

Comment: в начале в теге <head>

Comment: проверьте правильный ли путь к jquery

Comment: путь верный, файрбаг пишет вот: TypeError: $("#city") is null
[Прерывать на этой ошибке]  

$("#city").change(function(){var myChoice = $('#city :selected').val();

Comment: ну это я понял еще когда вы первый раз написали... 
а я предлагаю возможные варианты находжения ошибки...
вот бы весь код страницы на которой форма.

Comment: мне на почту... в профиле есть

Comment: Ок, не буду изменять, Я вашу почту не нашел, или написать туда где обратная связь?

Answer (score 0):

```
var top_list = [data.myrowRaion]; // содержимое новых элементов
```

А разве не должно быть просто:

```
var top_list = data.myrowRaion; // содержимое новых элементов
```

По идее, у Вас получится

```
top_list - [[array from json]] И в итоге top_list[i/*0*/] == data.myrowRaion
```

если

> "firebug пишет TypeError: $("#city")
> is null"

то нету у вас селекта с `ID city` - может имя только указали?

Если не хотите добавлять `id` то можете попробовать:

```
$("input[name='city']")
```

Comment: посмотрите что за ответ приходит? если  в хроме то F12 и там network

Comment: на 3 строке ошибка, вроде все в норме(

Comment: ничего не понимаю, что еще надо этому долбаному коду:)(

Comment: firebug так и пишет TypeError: $("#city") is null ?

Answer (score 0):

Так то в `php` коде где запрос идет вместо

```
 $resultRaion = mysql_query("SELECT raion, id FROM raion WHERE idCity = 'myChoice' ", $db);
```

должно, наверно, быть

```
$resultRaion = mysql_query("SELECT raion, id FROM raion WHERE idCity = '".$myChoice."' ", $db);
```

Да, кстати, а входящие параметры перед отправкой в `SQL` обезопасить не надо?

В `Ajax` запросе меняйте
    var myChoice = $('#city :selected').val()

на

var myChoice = $("form select[name=city] option:selected").val();

Comment: мне бы с начало без них выполнить задачу:) 
С выборкой проблемы, jquery не видит id="city":( 
ТОчно сделаю как вы написали

Comment: Пробовал не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Этот код должен работать? Ошибки на каждом шагу. Разберем по порядку, которые сразу бросились в глаза:

1.Получение значение селекта

```
$('#city :selected').val();
```

достаточно просто

```
$('#city').val();
```

2.Нужно более просто конструировать варианты второго селекта

```
var items = 'option';     
$mylist = $('#raion');                //где var??
for (var i=0; i top_list.length; i++)
    items +=  top_list[i] + '/option';  //получается только один открывающий option стоит?
$mylist.append(items);
```

(>< намеренно убрал, потому верстка съезжала) это переписывается так:

```
for (var i=0; i< top_list.length; i++){
    $("<option />", {html: top_list[i]}).appendTo('#raion');
}
```

думаю, что красиво :)

3.Вся вот эта штука по сборке первого селекта.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($resultCity) > 0){
       $myrowCity = mysql_fetch_array($resultCity);
       do{
           printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",$myrowCity["id"], $myrowCity["city"]); 
       }while ($myrowCity = mysql_fetch_array($resultCity));
    }else {
       echo "<p>Таблицы еще пустые, записей отствует</p>";
       exit ();
    }
```

Можно переписать так:

```
while($myrowCity = mysql_fetch_array($resultCity))
      printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",$myrowCity["id"], $myrowCity["city"]);
```

4.Здесь вот не до конца понял. Почему на форме есть какойто список районов, если Вы его будите перерисовывать данными из аякс-запроса?:

```
<p class="formP">Район:</p>
<select name="raion" id="raion">
<option>Кутузовка</option>
<option>Заречка</option>
<option>15мкрн</option>
<option>новый город</option>
</select>
```

Автор, я ни в коем случае не против вашего кода, я вижу что Вы находитесь только в начале пути, но себя сразу нужно приучать писать кратко, лаконично, красиво. Тогда ошибки будут видны сразу и их легко будет исправлять.

Comment: Пробовал все как вы написали, пока результатов нет( Спасибо за помощь